# Solve and plot an example

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I was working on this example but I don't know where I did a mistake?!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
y1[x_] = Sqrt[- a (1 - 2/(3 b) ) + x^2 f];
sol = DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t], x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]
Plot[y[x] /. sol /. {a -> 0.002, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Are you asking why you see an error or why you don't get a plot?

Comment: Use `NDSolve`. `y1[x_] = Sqrt[-a (1 - 2/(3 b)) + x^2 f];
sol = NDSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t] /. {a -> 0.002, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}, 
   x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 1, 10}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 1, 10}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

y1[x_] = Sqrt[-a (1 - 2/(3 b)) + x^2 f];

sol = DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t], x[0] == 1}, x[t], t] //
   
   FullSimplify[#, Thread[{a, b, f, t} > 0]] & //
  Quiet
```

[image]

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Simplify[
   x[t] /. sol /. 
    {a -> 1/500, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}]],
 {t, 1, 10},
 PlotRange -> {-50, 50},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

`1` and `2` are mirror images as are `3` and `4`.

```
Plus @@@ Partition[x[t] /. sol, 2]

(* {0, 0} *)
```